# Desktop notification

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome

I would like to create a notification, which appears, when turning the Caps Lock on/off. I am using GNOME and I tried the 
`notify-send`, but it is too "busy" and involving and I want something more quickly dissapearing.
I tried `xmessage`, but it is even more busy that this.

I want something like the dialog, when pressing Alt-Tab or changing the language. Something appearing for a short time.

I will appreciate the help!

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/

Comment: Hey, thanks, but not exactly what I was looking for. I want to write a script, which displays a notification, when I turn Caps lock on.
I am searching for the right way, and I don't like the interface of 'notify-send' and 'xmessage'

Comment: I just tried that extension and it displays a notification when you turn Caps Lock on. If you want it to look like the alt-tab popup you'll have to write your own extension.

Comment: Define "busy", do you meen there's too much GUI decoration or do you just mean it stays visible too long (*busy* doesn't carry that meaning). Sadly, there seems to be [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508) where the notify system ignores the `-t` timeout setting from `notify-send`. It seems to affect Ubuntu in general and also Gnome. If you're running Gnome or Cinnamon, it will also probably affect you.

Comment: Both. Thanks. I will try some other notification server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass options to `notify-send` to make it less obtrusive, e.g. `notify-send -u low -t 500` to show the message for only ½s.

I don't know what you mean by “busy”; the visual appearance of a notification is determined by the recipient side. If you don't like the one provided by Gnome, I think you can change it (e.g. to `xfce4-notifyd` which I don't think can be described as “busy”).